# Which Database to use for CMS project in ASP.NET - SQLite or SQL server compact?

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, content-management-system, sql-server-ce

I am working on a CMS project using ASP.Net 3.5/Visual studio 2008.This is the first week of the project and I am working on the design of the system right now.

Needless to say that this is my first project of this scale and I have no idea of what I am doing.

The requirements of the project ask for a light but functional CMS, one which is easy to deploy.So the question is which database to use in this scenario SQLCE or SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SQL Express with the Entity Framework.  There are just too many gotchas with SQLCE and SQLite - things that work just fine with SQL Express but which don't work with either one or both of these.

Sure they offer a slightly easier install path but SQL Express is a free download and it's not hard to install.